# Java: Cannot implement abstract method taking generic argument

Tags: java, inheritance, netbeans, abstract-class

I have an abstract class; one of whose abstract methods takes in a polymorphic argument as follows:

```
public abstract class MetricFunction<T extends MetricFunction> {

    public abstract double NDerv(int dervIndex, List<Double> evalPoint);

}
```

Now I attempt to extend this class and implement this abstract method as follows:

```
public class NumericMetricFunction extends MetricFunction {

    @Override
    public double NDerv(int dervIndex, List<Double> evalPoint) {

        //Do something...
        double answer = 0.;

        return answer;
    }
}
```

This fails. The IDE (NetBeans in this case) tells me that this method *NDerv* in *NumericMetricFunction* does not override a method of the superclass *MetricFunction*. At the same time, NetBeans acknowledges that the two methods have the same "erasure" (which I assume is a synonym to 'signature').

The IDE advises me that I should instead implement the abstract method as follows:

```
    @Override
    public double NDerv(int dervIndex, List evalPoint) {

        //Do something...
        double answer = 0.;

        return answer;
    }
```

When I do this, everything seems to work. However, I lose the more specific type of "evalPoint" as it is now just a generic list.

Why is this happening? What can I do to override this abstract method and still ensure that "evalPoint" is of type *List< Double >*? I don't want to typecast as that is poor practice; I don't see any reason why my original attempt shouldn't work.

**Update:**
I have slightly altered the code to correctly reproduce the problem.

Comment: The only reason that I could see for this error, is that inside either MetricFunction or NumericMetricFunction, you have *another* type called `Double` in scope (other than in the other instance). For example, you may have defined your own member class called `Double` or you may have imported another `Double` than the normal one from `java.lang.Double`.

Comment: I have said "Double" out of convenience; in actual fact I am using a class called "Real" which I have just confirmed is imported from the same library in both class files.

Comment: The code you shown will not give any error. There must be some other problem. You might be having different `Real` class.

Comment: no reason it won't work. you over simplified the example IMO.

Comment: @Fakrudeen - Okay, I will have a look and see if this is the case.

Comment: Your problem is that NUmericMetricFunction doesn't give a type to MetricFunction

Comment: What is the point of the type parameter `T`? You are not using it! Additionally, if not specifying a type argument (while extending your class), you are switching to the _raw_ mechanism, especially for all used generic types in the class. That means, you have to override the method `double NDerv(int dervIndex, List evalPoint)` (using raw type again), not `double NDerv(int dervIndex, List<Double> evalPoint)`.

Comment: @Seelenvurtuose - I don't understand what you mean by this "raw mechanism" I'm afraid. The type parameter has use in the unabridged code in my actual project-- some methods in MetricFunction return type T.

Answer (score 3):

Your abstract class is generic, but your implementing class doesn't pass  a parameter to it. If you redo your implementing class like this, it will pass:

```
public class NumericMetricFunction extends MetricFunction<NumericMetricFunction> {

    @Override
    public double NDerv(int dervIndex, List<Double> evalPoint) {

        //Do something...
        double answer = 0.;

        return answer;
    }
}
```

Comment: I will not be able to do this because I already have *MetricFunction* written as a polymorphic class. (I have simplified the code for this question). Besides, this seems more like a workaround.

Comment: It would make the compiler shut up... but frankly, there's nothing wrong with his example code, so he needs to give us a slightly more complex example.

Comment: So why am I able to implement other methods without passing this parameter? I know the issue now, but I have no understanding of why I was even allowed to continue the way I had up until I tried to implement this particular function.

Comment: So why did I not encounter any errors when declaring the class without a parameter?

Comment: The compiler registers not passing a parameter to a generic class as a warning, not an error. But when generics are involved (especially method overloading), it becomes important because the same function definition would not overload the function if the parameter was different, even if the erasure is the same. In practice, it makes no difference... but it confuses the compiler because the class hierarchy can't be established properly.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you located a bug. Actually, let's look what JLS's talking about your question (emphasize mine):

Section [8.4.8.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1)

> An instance method mC declared in or inherited by class C, overrides
>   from C another method mA declared in class A, **iff** all of the following
>   are true:
>
> A is a superclass of C.
>
> C does not inherit mA.
>
> **The signature of mC is a subsignature (§8.4.2) of the signature of**
>   **mA.**
>
> One of the following is true:
>
> - mA is public.
>
> [...]

**The first point** is obvious.

**The second point** is true because your class doesn't inherit the method from superclass becuase of the same erasure.

**The third point** is also true, but needs some notes. The subsignature means ([JLS 8.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2))

> The signature of a method m1 is a subsignature of the signature of a
>   method m2 if either:
>
> - m2 has the same signature as m1, or
> - **the signature of m1 is the same as the erasure (§4.6) of the**
>     **signature of m2.**

Again, because of the same erasure it's true.

**The fourth point** is obvious either.

So, your code should have been compiled fine.

`Ideone`'s compiler doesn't compile it either. [Demo](http://ideone.com/yWIE3s)

Comment: I don't think so. The super type here is a raw type, therefore the method mA has the erased signature. But that point is not really relevant in this problem. The important thing is, mC is *not* a subsignature of mA, because the signature of mC, a generic signature, is not the same as the erasure of the signature of mA.

Comment: If mA is generic, and mC is not, it is likely that mA was non-generic before it was generified; mC was overriding the old mA, and mC has not been generified after the new mA. For migration compatibility, mC is still considered an overriding method of mA. And that's the motivation behind the definition of subsignature.

Comment: @bayou.io Couldn't you explain why you think __the signature of mC, a generic signature, is not the same as the erasure of the signature of mA__? According to [4.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6) their erassures are completely the same.

Comment: the clause says `m1=|m2|` ; it does not say `|m1|=|m2|`

Comment: What exactly is the erasure of m2 here? Is it (int, List <?>) ?

Comment: @bayou.io - You say that mC's signature is not the same as the erasure of mA. I think this explains why the compiler allows me to use *List* but not *List< Double >*. However, why am I allowed to use *List < Double >* after I have made *C* extend *A < C >*?

Comment: @Myridium - you are extending a raw type `MetricFunction`. Java treats raw types very harshly; in particular, all methods in a raw type have signature erased completely. Therefore, the raw `MetricFunction` has a method `NDerv(int,List)` with `List<Double>` erased; the subtype of the raw `MetricFunction` can only override this erased method.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to use generic type:

```
public abstract class MetricFunction<T extends Number> {

    public abstract double NDerv(int dervIndex, List<T> evalPoint);

}
```

Using it:

```
public class NumericMetricFunction extends MetricFunction<Double> {

    @Override
    public double NDerv(int dervIndex, List<Double> evalPoint) {

    }

}
```

Comment: As I already said in response to a similar answer, I cannot do this as: 1) It does not solve my problem; it is a workaround. 2) MetricFunction is already a polymorphic type in my actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Its I think its an **IDE issue**, as I tried the same in Eclipse.

- **Eclipse** : Kepler
- **JAVA**    : 1.7

And it worked fine. Auto generated **@Override** had **List < Double>**

```
import java.util.List;

public abstract class MetricFunction {
    public abstract double NDerv(int dervIndex, List<Double> evalPoint);
}

import java.util.List;
```

Now extended it, override function automatically added.

```
import java.util.List;

public class NumericMetricFunction extends MetricFunction {

    @Override
    public double NDerv(int dervIndex, List<Double> evalPoint) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why this works, but I should have declared *NumericMetricFunction* as follows:

```
public class NumericMetricFunction extends MetricFunction<NumericMetricFunction> {...}
```